# Blank Login In sp_who2 Result

Tags: sql-server, security, logins, connections

There are some rows in the result of `sp_who2` which their `Login` column value is null (see image below) while the `login_name` column of `sys.dm_exec_sessions` is not blank and this sometimes happens conversely, what is the reason of this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Please read this https://littlekendra.com/2017/02/16/confused-by-sp_who2-dear-sql-dba-episode-30/ by kendra little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you stop using sp_who2, there are better ways to look at that information.  Even you do not want to use third party script you are better off joining following dmvs and get what you need.

sys.dm_exec_sessions 
sys.dm_exec_requests
sys.dm_exec_sql_text
sys.dm_exec_query_plan
sys.dm_os_tasks

I use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) by Adam Machanic and will not try to write anything by myself.

To answer your question session id 428 is running in parallel meaning multiple threads and you can see it using below query.  Login name is showing only for `exec_context_id =0` which is the parent thread.

```
SELECT er.session_id, 
       er.status, 
       er.command, 
       er.blocking_session_id, 
       er.wait_type, 
       th.os_thread_id,
       os.cpu_id,
       ot.exec_context_id, 
       ot.task_state, 
       st.text 
FROM   sys.dm_os_threads th 
inner join sys.dm_os_tasks ot on th.worker_address = ot.worker_address 
inner join sys.dm_exec_requests er on ot.session_id = er.session_id 
inner join sys.dm_os_schedulers os on th.scheduler_address = os.scheduler_address 
       CROSS apply sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) st 
WHERE  er.session_id IN (SELECT session_id 
                         FROM   sys.dm_os_tasks 
                         GROUP  BY session_id 
                         HAVING Count(exec_context_id) > 1
                         )
```

Comment: you are right about 'exec_context_id = 0', I didn't see the parent thread because it was SUSPENDED and I had filtered just RUNNING sessions. I got it from your query.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to check blank logins is to use the SSMS Activity monitor and use the filter logins category for 'Blank' underneath the processes tab. It will show the running process as blank while the session is logging into the DB from your RD sessions. I'm using that feature to check the latency between opening a session and the time it takes to login to the DB. If you just use sp_who2 then you'll only get a point in time reference while activity monitor will show the change from blank to logged in status.

[image]